# Creating a global variable to toggle (show/hide) a bunch of answer keys

Tags: programming

I have a bunch of simple trigonometric questions for warming up. Could you make a global variable `\showAnswer`  that accepts `true` or `false` (default) to show and hide the answer?

I prefer TeX solution than others.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a5paper,landscape]{article}
\usepackage[hmargin=5mm,vmargin=1.3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{3}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item $\displaystyle \tan 15^\circ = 2-\sqrt{3}$
    \item $\displaystyle \csc 300^\circ = -\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}$
    \item $\displaystyle \cos 255^\circ = -\frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{2 \sqrt{2}}$
    \item $\displaystyle \cos 195^\circ = -\frac{1+\sqrt{3}}{2 \sqrt{2}}$
    \item $\displaystyle \sec 135^\circ = -\sqrt{2}$
    \item $\displaystyle \cos 330^\circ = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$
    \item $\displaystyle \tan 315^\circ = -1$
    \item $\displaystyle \sec 75^\circ = \sqrt{2} \left(1+\sqrt{3}\right)$
    \item $\displaystyle \tan 255^\circ = 2+\sqrt{3}$
    \item $\displaystyle \csc 255^\circ = -\sqrt{2} \left(\sqrt{3}-1\right)$
    \item $\displaystyle \csc 135^\circ = \sqrt{2}$
    \item $\displaystyle \cos 120^\circ = -\frac{1}{2}$
    \item $\displaystyle \tan 330^\circ = -\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$
    \item $\displaystyle \sec 120^\circ = -2$
    \item $\displaystyle \cot 315^\circ = -1$
    \item $\displaystyle \sin 30^\circ = \frac{1}{2}$
    \item $\displaystyle \sec 285^\circ = \sqrt{2} \left(1+\sqrt{3}\right)$
    \item $\displaystyle \csc 195^\circ = -\sqrt{2} \left(1+\sqrt{3}\right)$
    \item $\displaystyle \cot 180^\circ = \infty$
    \item $\displaystyle \cot 330^\circ = -\sqrt{3}$
    \item $\displaystyle \sec 0^\circ = 1$
    \item $\displaystyle \cos 210^\circ = -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$
    \item $\displaystyle \sin 165^\circ = \frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{2 \sqrt{2}}$
    \item $\displaystyle \sin 15^\circ = \frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{2 \sqrt{2}}$
    \item $\displaystyle \sin 90^\circ = 1$
    \item $\displaystyle \sin 225^\circ = -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$
    \item $\displaystyle \cot 75^\circ = 2-\sqrt{3}$
    \item $\displaystyle \tan 240^\circ = \sqrt{3}$
    \item $\displaystyle \sin 210^\circ = -\frac{1}{2}$
    \item $\displaystyle \cos 270^\circ = 0$
    \item $\displaystyle \sin 255^\circ = -\frac{1+\sqrt{3}}{2 \sqrt{2}}$
    \item $\displaystyle \sec 270^\circ = \infty$
    \item $\displaystyle \sin 285^\circ = -\frac{1+\sqrt{3}}{2 \sqrt{2}}$
    \item $\displaystyle \tan 285^\circ = -2-\sqrt{3}$
    \item $\displaystyle \csc 165^\circ = \sqrt{2} \left(1+\sqrt{3}\right)$
    \item $\displaystyle \sec 45^\circ = \sqrt{2}$
    \item $\displaystyle \sin 345^\circ = -\frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{2 \sqrt{2}}$
    \item $\displaystyle \csc 180^\circ = \infty$
    \item $\displaystyle \cos 180^\circ = -1$
    \item $\displaystyle \cot 105^\circ = \sqrt{3}-2$
    \item $\displaystyle \tan 30^\circ = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$
    \item $\displaystyle \sec 330^\circ = \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}$
    \item $\displaystyle \csc 150^\circ = 2$
    \item $\displaystyle \sin 180^\circ = 0$
    \item $\displaystyle \cos 285^\circ = \frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{2 \sqrt{2}}$
    \item $\displaystyle \cos 15^\circ = \frac{1+\sqrt{3}}{2 \sqrt{2}}$
    \item $\displaystyle \tan 225^\circ = 1$
    \item $\displaystyle \cot 300^\circ = -\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$
    \item $\displaystyle \cot 135^\circ = -1$
    \item $\displaystyle \sec 60^\circ = 2$
    \item $\displaystyle \sin 195^\circ = -\frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{2 \sqrt{2}}$
    \item $\displaystyle \cot 120^\circ = -\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$
    \item $\displaystyle \cos 165^\circ = -\frac{1+\sqrt{3}}{2 \sqrt{2}}$
    \item $\displaystyle \sec 240^\circ = -2$
    \item $\displaystyle \cos 240^\circ = -\frac{1}{2}$
    \item $\displaystyle \csc 75^\circ = \sqrt{2} \left(\sqrt{3}-1\right)$
    \item $\displaystyle \tan 90^\circ = \infty$
    \item $\displaystyle \cos 225^\circ = -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$
    \item $\displaystyle \tan 105^\circ = -2-\sqrt{3}$
    \item $\displaystyle \tan 195^\circ = 2-\sqrt{3}$
    \item $\displaystyle \cot 210^\circ = \sqrt{3}$
    \item $\displaystyle \cos 75^\circ = \frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{2 \sqrt{2}}$
    \item $\displaystyle \cot 195^\circ = 2+\sqrt{3}$
    \item $\displaystyle \sec 345^\circ = -\sqrt{2} \left(1-\sqrt{3}\right)$
    \item $\displaystyle \sec 105^\circ = -\sqrt{2} \left(1+\sqrt{3}\right)$
    \item $\displaystyle \cot 270^\circ = 0$
    \item $\displaystyle \cos 135^\circ = -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$
    \item $\displaystyle \csc 240^\circ = -\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}$
    \item $\displaystyle \sec 315^\circ = \sqrt{2}$
    \item $\displaystyle \cot 150^\circ = -\sqrt{3}$
    \item $\displaystyle \cot 45^\circ = 1$
    \item $\displaystyle \sin 135^\circ = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$
    \item $\displaystyle \csc 315^\circ = -\sqrt{2}$
    \item $\displaystyle \sec 15^\circ = \sqrt{2} \left(\sqrt{3}-1\right)$
    \item $\displaystyle \sec 180^\circ = -1$
    \item $\displaystyle \sec 300^\circ = 2$
    \item $\displaystyle \csc 330^\circ = -2$
    \item $\displaystyle \csc 45^\circ = \sqrt{2}$
    \item $\displaystyle \csc 285^\circ = \sqrt{2} \left(1-\sqrt{3}\right)$
    \item $\displaystyle \sec 195^\circ = -\sqrt{2} \left(\sqrt{3}-1\right)$
    \item $\displaystyle \csc 15^\circ = \sqrt{2} \left(1+\sqrt{3}\right)$
    \item $\displaystyle \sec 255^\circ = -\sqrt{2} \left(1+\sqrt{3}\right)$
    \item $\displaystyle \sin 60^\circ = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$
    \item $\displaystyle \sec 150^\circ = -\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}$
    \item $\displaystyle \cot 90^\circ = 0$
    \item $\displaystyle \sin 0^\circ = 0$
    \item $\displaystyle \cot 30^\circ = \sqrt{3}$
    \item $\displaystyle \csc 270^\circ = -1$
    \item $\displaystyle \sec 90^\circ = \infty$
    \item $\displaystyle \tan 0^\circ = 0$
    \item $\displaystyle \cos 345^\circ = \frac{1+\sqrt{3}}{2 \sqrt{2}}$
    \item $\displaystyle \sin 300^\circ = -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$
    \item $\displaystyle \csc 60^\circ = \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}$
    \item $\displaystyle \tan 210^\circ = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$
    \item $\displaystyle \cos 300^\circ = \frac{1}{2}$
    \item $\displaystyle \tan 75^\circ = 2+\sqrt{3}$
    \item $\displaystyle \tan 345^\circ = \sqrt{3}-2$
    \item $\displaystyle \sin 45^\circ = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$
    \item $\displaystyle \cos 30^\circ = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$
    \item $\displaystyle \sec 210^\circ = -\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}$
    \item $\displaystyle \cot 165^\circ = -2-\sqrt{3}$
    \item $\displaystyle \sin 75^\circ = \frac{1+\sqrt{3}}{2 \sqrt{2}}$
    \item $\displaystyle \cos 0^\circ = 1$
    \item $\displaystyle \cot 285^\circ = \sqrt{3}-2$
    \item $\displaystyle \cot 60^\circ = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$
    \item $\displaystyle \sin 270^\circ = -1$
    \item $\displaystyle \cos 315^\circ = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$
    \item $\displaystyle \csc 345^\circ = -\sqrt{2} \left(1+\sqrt{3}\right)$
    \item $\displaystyle \tan 180^\circ = 0$
    \item $\displaystyle \cot 15^\circ = 2+\sqrt{3}$
    \item $\displaystyle \csc 30^\circ = 2$
    \item $\displaystyle \tan 165^\circ = \sqrt{3}-2$
    \item $\displaystyle \tan 300^\circ = -\sqrt{3}$
    \item $\displaystyle \tan 120^\circ = -\sqrt{3}$
    \item $\displaystyle \sin 330^\circ = -\frac{1}{2}$
    \item $\displaystyle \csc 0^\circ = \infty$
    \item $\displaystyle \tan 150^\circ = -\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$
    \item $\displaystyle \sec 30^\circ = \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}$
    \item $\displaystyle \sin 315^\circ = -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$
    \item $\displaystyle \cot 225^\circ = 1$
    \item $\displaystyle \cos 45^\circ = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$
    \item $\displaystyle \cot 255^\circ = 2-\sqrt{3}$
    \item $\displaystyle \cot 0^\circ = \infty$
    \item $\displaystyle \cos 150^\circ = -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$
    \item $\displaystyle \sin 240^\circ = -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$
    \item $\displaystyle \csc 120^\circ = \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}$
    \item $\displaystyle \cot 240^\circ = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$
    \item $\displaystyle \sin 105^\circ = \frac{1+\sqrt{3}}{2 \sqrt{2}}$
    \item $\displaystyle \csc 90^\circ = 1$
    \item $\displaystyle \csc 105^\circ = -\sqrt{2} \left(1-\sqrt{3}\right)$
    \item $\displaystyle \cos 60^\circ = \frac{1}{2}$
    \item $\displaystyle \sec 225^\circ = -\sqrt{2}$
    \item $\displaystyle \tan 135^\circ = -1$
    \item $\displaystyle \tan 45^\circ = 1$
    \item $\displaystyle \cot 345^\circ = -2-\sqrt{3}$
    \item $\displaystyle \tan 270^\circ = \infty$
    \item $\displaystyle \cos 105^\circ = -\frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{2 \sqrt{2}}$
    \item $\displaystyle \tan 60^\circ = \sqrt{3}$
    \item $\displaystyle \sin 120^\circ = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$
    \item $\displaystyle \cos 90^\circ = 0$
    \item $\displaystyle \sec 165^\circ = \sqrt{2} \left(1-\sqrt{3}\right)$
    \item $\displaystyle \csc 210^\circ = -2$
    \item $\displaystyle \csc 225^\circ = -\sqrt{2}$
    \item $\displaystyle \sin 150^\circ = \frac{1}{2}$
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @JohnKormylo: But sandwiching each item will increase  the file size exponentially.  :-) Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, within the `multicols` environment, I make `=` active, and, depending on the value of `\showanswer` (`T` or `F`), I either display the answer or a `\phantom` of the answer.

This approach relies on there being only one `=` in each answer, and on the use of `$` delimiters for the math (as opposed to, for example, `\(...\)`).

The key code...in fact, the only changes to the OP's MWE are these: in the preamble,

```
\newif\ifshowanswer
%\showanswertrue
\let\sveq==
```

and in the `multicols` environment,

```
\catcode`\= \active
\ifshowanswer \def=#1${\sveq#1$}\else\def=#1${\sveq\phantom{#1}$}\fi
```

The MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a5paper,landscape]{article}
\usepackage[hmargin=5mm,vmargin=1.3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\newif\ifshowanswer
%\showanswertrue
\let\sveq==
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{3}
\catcode`\= \active
\ifshowanswer \def=#1${\sveq#1$}\else\def=#1${\sveq\phantom{#1}$}\fi
\begin{enumerate}
    \item $\displaystyle \tan 15^\circ = 2-\sqrt{3}$
    \item $\displaystyle \csc 300^\circ = -\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}$
    \item $\displaystyle \cos 255^\circ = -\frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{2 \sqrt{2}}$
    \item $\displaystyle \cos 195^\circ = -\frac{1+\sqrt{3}}{2 \sqrt{2}}$
    \item $\displaystyle \sec 135^\circ = -\sqrt{2}$
    \item $\displaystyle \cos 330^\circ = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$
    \item $\displaystyle \tan 315^\circ = -1$
    \item $\displaystyle \sec 75^\circ = \sqrt{2} \left(1+\sqrt{3}\right)$
    \item $\displaystyle \tan 255^\circ = 2+\sqrt{3}$
    \item $\displaystyle \csc 255^\circ = -\sqrt{2} \left(\sqrt{3}-1\right)$
    \item $\displaystyle \csc 135^\circ = \sqrt{2}$
    \item $\displaystyle \cos 120^\circ = -\frac{1}{2}$
    \item $\displaystyle \tan 330^\circ = -\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$
    \item $\displaystyle \sec 120^\circ = -2$
    \item $\displaystyle \cot 315^\circ = -1$
    \item $\displaystyle \sin 30^\circ = \frac{1}{2}$
    \item $\displaystyle \sec 285^\circ = \sqrt{2} \left(1+\sqrt{3}\right)$
    \item $\displaystyle \csc 195^\circ = -\sqrt{2} \left(1+\sqrt{3}\right)$
    \item $\displaystyle \cot 180^\circ = \infty$
    \item $\displaystyle \cot 330^\circ = -\sqrt{3}$
    \item $\displaystyle \sec 0^\circ = 1$
    \item $\displaystyle \cos 210^\circ = -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$
    \item $\displaystyle \sin 165^\circ = \frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{2 \sqrt{2}}$
    \item $\displaystyle \sin 15^\circ = \frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{2 \sqrt{2}}$
    \item $\displaystyle \sin 90^\circ = 1$
    \item $\displaystyle \sin 225^\circ = -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$
    \item $\displaystyle \cot 75^\circ = 2-\sqrt{3}$
    \item $\displaystyle \tan 240^\circ = \sqrt{3}$
    \item $\displaystyle \sin 210^\circ = -\frac{1}{2}$
    \item $\displaystyle \cos 270^\circ = 0$
    \item $\displaystyle \sin 255^\circ = -\frac{1+\sqrt{3}}{2 \sqrt{2}}$
    \item $\displaystyle \sec 270^\circ = \infty$
    \item $\displaystyle \sin 285^\circ = -\frac{1+\sqrt{3}}{2 \sqrt{2}}$
    \item $\displaystyle \tan 285^\circ = -2-\sqrt{3}$
    \item $\displaystyle \csc 165^\circ = \sqrt{2} \left(1+\sqrt{3}\right)$
    \item $\displaystyle \sec 45^\circ = \sqrt{2}$
    \item $\displaystyle \sin 345^\circ = -\frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{2 \sqrt{2}}$
    \item $\displaystyle \csc 180^\circ = \infty$
    \item $\displaystyle \cos 180^\circ = -1$
    \item $\displaystyle \cot 105^\circ = \sqrt{3}-2$
    \item $\displaystyle \tan 30^\circ = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$
    \item $\displaystyle \sec 330^\circ = \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}$
    \item $\displaystyle \csc 150^\circ = 2$
    \item $\displaystyle \sin 180^\circ = 0$
    \item $\displaystyle \cos 285^\circ = \frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{2 \sqrt{2}}$
    \item $\displaystyle \cos 15^\circ = \frac{1+\sqrt{3}}{2 \sqrt{2}}$
    \item $\displaystyle \tan 225^\circ = 1$
    \item $\displaystyle \cot 300^\circ = -\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$
    \item $\displaystyle \cot 135^\circ = -1$
    \item $\displaystyle \sec 60^\circ = 2$
    \item $\displaystyle \sin 195^\circ = -\frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{2 \sqrt{2}}$
    \item $\displaystyle \cot 120^\circ = -\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$
    \item $\displaystyle \cos 165^\circ = -\frac{1+\sqrt{3}}{2 \sqrt{2}}$
    \item $\displaystyle \sec 240^\circ = -2$
    \item $\displaystyle \cos 240^\circ = -\frac{1}{2}$
    \item $\displaystyle \csc 75^\circ = \sqrt{2} \left(\sqrt{3}-1\right)$
    \item $\displaystyle \tan 90^\circ = \infty$
    \item $\displaystyle \cos 225^\circ = -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$
    \item $\displaystyle \tan 105^\circ = -2-\sqrt{3}$
    \item $\displaystyle \tan 195^\circ = 2-\sqrt{3}$
    \item $\displaystyle \cot 210^\circ = \sqrt{3}$
    \item $\displaystyle \cos 75^\circ = \frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{2 \sqrt{2}}$
    \item $\displaystyle \cot 195^\circ = 2+\sqrt{3}$
    \item $\displaystyle \sec 345^\circ = -\sqrt{2} \left(1-\sqrt{3}\right)$
    \item $\displaystyle \sec 105^\circ = -\sqrt{2} \left(1+\sqrt{3}\right)$
    \item $\displaystyle \cot 270^\circ = 0$
    \item $\displaystyle \cos 135^\circ = -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$
    \item $\displaystyle \csc 240^\circ = -\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}$
    \item $\displaystyle \sec 315^\circ = \sqrt{2}$
    \item $\displaystyle \cot 150^\circ = -\sqrt{3}$
    \item $\displaystyle \cot 45^\circ = 1$
    \item $\displaystyle \sin 135^\circ = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$
    \item $\displaystyle \csc 315^\circ = -\sqrt{2}$
    \item $\displaystyle \sec 15^\circ = \sqrt{2} \left(\sqrt{3}-1\right)$
    \item $\displaystyle \sec 180^\circ = -1$
    \item $\displaystyle \sec 300^\circ = 2$
    \item $\displaystyle \csc 330^\circ = -2$
    \item $\displaystyle \csc 45^\circ = \sqrt{2}$
    \item $\displaystyle \csc 285^\circ = \sqrt{2} \left(1-\sqrt{3}\right)$
    \item $\displaystyle \sec 195^\circ = -\sqrt{2} \left(\sqrt{3}-1\right)$
    \item $\displaystyle \csc 15^\circ = \sqrt{2} \left(1+\sqrt{3}\right)$
    \item $\displaystyle \sec 255^\circ = -\sqrt{2} \left(1+\sqrt{3}\right)$
    \item $\displaystyle \sin 60^\circ = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$
    \item $\displaystyle \sec 150^\circ = -\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}$
    \item $\displaystyle \cot 90^\circ = 0$
    \item $\displaystyle \sin 0^\circ = 0$
    \item $\displaystyle \cot 30^\circ = \sqrt{3}$
    \item $\displaystyle \csc 270^\circ = -1$
    \item $\displaystyle \sec 90^\circ = \infty$
    \item $\displaystyle \tan 0^\circ = 0$
    \item $\displaystyle \cos 345^\circ = \frac{1+\sqrt{3}}{2 \sqrt{2}}$
    \item $\displaystyle \sin 300^\circ = -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$
    \item $\displaystyle \csc 60^\circ = \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}$
    \item $\displaystyle \tan 210^\circ = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$
    \item $\displaystyle \cos 300^\circ = \frac{1}{2}$
    \item $\displaystyle \tan 75^\circ = 2+\sqrt{3}$
    \item $\displaystyle \tan 345^\circ = \sqrt{3}-2$
    \item $\displaystyle \sin 45^\circ = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$
    \item $\displaystyle \cos 30^\circ = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$
    \item $\displaystyle \sec 210^\circ = -\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}$
    \item $\displaystyle \cot 165^\circ = -2-\sqrt{3}$
    \item $\displaystyle \sin 75^\circ = \frac{1+\sqrt{3}}{2 \sqrt{2}}$
    \item $\displaystyle \cos 0^\circ = 1$
    \item $\displaystyle \cot 285^\circ = \sqrt{3}-2$
    \item $\displaystyle \cot 60^\circ = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$
    \item $\displaystyle \sin 270^\circ = -1$
    \item $\displaystyle \cos 315^\circ = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$
    \item $\displaystyle \csc 345^\circ = -\sqrt{2} \left(1+\sqrt{3}\right)$
    \item $\displaystyle \tan 180^\circ = 0$
    \item $\displaystyle \cot 15^\circ = 2+\sqrt{3}$
    \item $\displaystyle \csc 30^\circ = 2$
    \item $\displaystyle \tan 165^\circ = \sqrt{3}-2$
    \item $\displaystyle \tan 300^\circ = -\sqrt{3}$
    \item $\displaystyle \tan 120^\circ = -\sqrt{3}$
    \item $\displaystyle \sin 330^\circ = -\frac{1}{2}$
    \item $\displaystyle \csc 0^\circ = \infty$
    \item $\displaystyle \tan 150^\circ = -\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$
    \item $\displaystyle \sec 30^\circ = \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}$
    \item $\displaystyle \sin 315^\circ = -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$
    \item $\displaystyle \cot 225^\circ = 1$
    \item $\displaystyle \cos 45^\circ = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$
    \item $\displaystyle \cot 255^\circ = 2-\sqrt{3}$
    \item $\displaystyle \cot 0^\circ = \infty$
    \item $\displaystyle \cos 150^\circ = -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$
    \item $\displaystyle \sin 240^\circ = -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$
    \item $\displaystyle \csc 120^\circ = \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}$
    \item $\displaystyle \cot 240^\circ = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$
    \item $\displaystyle \sin 105^\circ = \frac{1+\sqrt{3}}{2 \sqrt{2}}$
    \item $\displaystyle \csc 90^\circ = 1$
    \item $\displaystyle \csc 105^\circ = -\sqrt{2} \left(1-\sqrt{3}\right)$
    \item $\displaystyle \cos 60^\circ = \frac{1}{2}$
    \item $\displaystyle \sec 225^\circ = -\sqrt{2}$
    \item $\displaystyle \tan 135^\circ = -1$
    \item $\displaystyle \tan 45^\circ = 1$
    \item $\displaystyle \cot 345^\circ = -2-\sqrt{3}$
    \item $\displaystyle \tan 270^\circ = \infty$
    \item $\displaystyle \cos 105^\circ = -\frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{2 \sqrt{2}}$
    \item $\displaystyle \tan 60^\circ = \sqrt{3}$
    \item $\displaystyle \sin 120^\circ = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$
    \item $\displaystyle \cos 90^\circ = 0$
    \item $\displaystyle \sec 165^\circ = \sqrt{2} \left(1-\sqrt{3}\right)$
    \item $\displaystyle \csc 210^\circ = -2$
    \item $\displaystyle \csc 225^\circ = -\sqrt{2}$
    \item $\displaystyle \sin 150^\circ = \frac{1}{2}$
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

FALSE version

[image]

TRUE version

[image]

As I noted in a later comment, I made it so the blank answers take up the exact same space as if the answers were present. Otherwise, repagination would occur when changing from showanswer false to true. If you wanted the blank answer sheet to provide uniform spaces, you could replace the one line with this: `\ifshowanswer \def=#1${\sveq#1$}\else\def=#1${\sveq$}\fi`, getting rid of the `\phantom{#1}`.

Comment: Do you notice the first four questions are not evenly distributed in vertical direction? You intentionally made it?

Comment: @MoneyOrientedProgrammer I made it so they take up the exact same space as if the answers were present.  Otherwise, repagination would occur when changing from showanswer false to true.  If you wanted the blank answer sheet to provide uniform spaces, you could replace the one line with this: `\ifshowanswer \def=#1${\sveq#1$}\else\def=#1${\sveq$}\fi`, getting rid of the `\phantom{#1}`.